# Forced voting mechanism for users who participated in a question

Tags: feature-request, voting

I come to the point directly.

1. There are many great questions and great answers on SO. Many of these get enough upvotes and yes they do deserve it. But some these great posts do not receive upvotes. I know this is just the nature of Stack Overflow but I will explain below.
2. There are bad posts as well. Surely most of us like to upvote a better post and we all do, and of course we SO discourages downvoting(I think this is the reason why it costs -1 for downvoting), but there are posts which must be downvoted and sometimes these posts do not get down voted just because people don't want to waste there reputation.

I just want to ask can we make a restriction on users that they should either vote up or vote down at-least one question or answer in every 5 participations (participation I mean comment or answer or maybe question as well).

**The benefits would be**

1. People will be forced upvote questions and answers  which are of better quality, so this will encourage people to post quality questions and answers on SO.
2. Low quality posts will get more down votes than what they get today, so it will eventually help these posts get deleted and help to improve the quality of the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many users who do care about Stack Overflow and care to up-vote, down-vote or do nothing when the question doesn't deserve voting at all.
Forcing someone to vote, up or down, is not a solution and won't make anything better here.

I honestly can't see how "*people will be forced vote up questions and answers*" is a benefit, forcing is bad, and regarding the low quality posts, they get downvoted by many users.

During my stay on Stack Overflow, I came across thousands of questions that didn't deserve any votes, I won't like it if the system will force me to vote on questions/answers and I'll leave the community as soon as it'll be mandatory :)

---

"*hey why the down vote.. is this a duplicate or off-topic*" -

[**On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @NaeemShaikh This is only my opinion :) there might be people who agree with you.

Comment: yes maroun.. I will just wait if someone agrees with my point.. I still agree  the last paragraph in your answer does answer my question very well.